# How to get validation error message from EdiText in android native application by using UIAUTOMATOR

Tags: android, python, android-uiautomator

I am trying to automate a native application in android.In that application I have login functionality.I automated the positive flow.Now I am trying to get the error message which is showing in a popup if i wont fill the Email field.This popup is not identify by the UIAUTOMATORVIEWER.

I am using python and UIAUTOMATOR.Someone please suggest me how to get the error message which is showing in the popup.

Below I am attaching the image.
[image: error message in popup.]

I want to print 'Field cannot be empty' message shown in the popup.

```
print self.d(text='Email').text
```

giving the 'Email' text not the 'Field cant be empty' message.

Comment: u can make a custom view as visibility.gone and can make it visible for error. may be not according to your question but simple approach for native android

Comment: I didn't get your point.Can you give me the brief explanation on that.

Comment: the link u above provide, showing a layout is xml based native layout right ?

Comment: Actually that is not the real application i am trying to automate.But the popup which i have in my application is also same as the image i provided.

Comment: if your layout is native xml based android layout u can easily make a view inside framelayout in your layout to appear over ur edittext & initially make in invisible, and when u get an error then programmatically make it visible

Comment: Thanks for your help@SmartphoneDeveloper. I posted an image what exactly i want.can you please tell me if you know the solution.

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood.I dont have any xml file with me.I have APk file with me and i need to test the application.I have to print the validation message ,to know whether the validations are happening correctly or not as a tester.I think your answer is for developer not for tester .am i correct?

Comment: O my.. I wrote all this as if u were having the xml file. I didnt realize that u were asking for Tester, obviously its for developer

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this code to give you a path. Do advancements as per your requirment :

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frame_for_email_error"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/Gray"
        android:text="Field cannot be empty"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And when your Email is !(email.length>0) do like this:

**Java code:**

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findviewbyid(R.id.frame_for_email_error);

frame.setvisibility(View.Visible);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to tell you but you can't. I've had that same problem (for that exact situation and others). All UiAutomator can see is what uiAutomatorViewer identifies.

P.s.: This is also why UiAutomator doesn't read/find an object that is not currently visible on the screen.